# What is the proper Reply URL for Postman?

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman

I've been using Postman with OAuth 2.0 for a few months after following the instructions in this excellent post: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-ad-b2c-webapi?view=aspnetcore-2.2.

This weekend it stopped working.  After taking the client credentials, I'm routed to the callback URL: https://getpostman.com/postman.  In the past, this has been enough to tell Postman to continue on with issuing the authentication token, but now I just get some promotional stuff from Postman.

Anyone know what's going on or whether I'm using the proper reply URL?

Answer (score 0):

I contacted support at Postman.  They gave me this URL which works pretty well.

https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback